# RegEx To Check if string contains 2 consecutive integers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been stuck trying to figure out how to write a regular expression that checks if a string contains 2 consecutive integers. For example 1,2  5,6  7,8.  Is this possible, or would it be smarter to break the string into an array, and check that way.

Comment: but from string like "1,2,3,4,8,7,6" or something more complex?

Comment: more complex IE  

string12 = true
string43 = false

Comment: Is your string like this: `123456` or like this: `1,2,3,4,5,6`?

Comment: you wanted two digits like 48 or two consexutive integer like 12, 67, 78?

Comment: See [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/gG6jJ6/1) `regex` demo

Comment: Is `01` or `001` valid?

Comment: @NickDelaney `\d{2}` will match any two digits (90, 76,44), not necessary consecutive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\d{2}
```

Check out usage here:

https://regex101.com/r/rQ8jY8/1

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!  I will accept once I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check two consecutive integers,

Then use the following regular expression,

```
[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: This is for a two-digit integer, not two **consecutive** integers

Answer (score 0):

For two consecutive integers one after another:

```
01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89
```

for two consecutive integers with some characters between but not digits:

```
0[^\d]*1|1[^\d]*2|2[^\d]*3|3[^\d]*4|4[^\d]*5|5[^\d]*6|6[^\d]*7|7[^\d]*8|8[^\d]*9
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zW5iP8/1)